# Data between elements

Tags: xhtml, xpath

I'm trying to retrieve data that's put outside element blocks.
Sample;

```
<td>
  <b>abc</b> 123 <b>def</b> 456 <b>ghi</b>
</td>
```

So from this sample I would like to get the 123 and 456.

On this site I found some samples with a not() and that seems to work a bit in the right direction but then 123 & 456 are removed because he only shows the 'other elements'.

So `/td/.[not(b)]` won't give results at all.

How can I make the date that isn't in an element apear again?

if I only use `/td` then the data outside an element is shown.

Thanks in advance,
      Edwin

Comment: You're going to have to clarify what you consdier to be "outside element blocks" because in your example 123 and 456 are both inside your <td/>.

Comment: i think it's pretty obvious what he wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `text()`. See [here for an example](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xsllist/200601/post20500.html) that is almost identical to you situation.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [XML Node Types](http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/dom_nodetype.asp), you can specify to only select text nodes. For example:

```
/td/text()
```

should return you a list of all the text nodes underneath td

Comment: A bit new to this site but I can't seem to flag your responce.
I'll register and mark it as helpfull! :)

Thanks to the both, still overwhelmed by the fast response.

Comment: My reputation isn't high enough yet to mark it but thanks again.

Comment: only 2 away from being able to upvote. btw flagging means that you think it is offensive. don't do that.